# Not able to start apache-nifi in aks

Tags: sed, apache-nifi, azure-aks

Hi all I am working on Nifi and I am trying to install it in AKS (Azure kubernetes service).
Using nifi 1.9.2 version. While installing it in AKS gives me an error

```
replacing target file  /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi.properties
sed: preserving permissions for ‘/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/sedSFiVwC’: Operation not permitted
replacing target file  /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi.properties
sed: preserving permissions for ‘/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/sedK3S1JJ’: Operation not permitted
replacing target file  /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi.properties
sed: preserving permissions for ‘/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/sedbcm91T’: Operation not permitted
replacing target file  /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi.properties
sed: preserving permissions for ‘/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/sedIuYSe1’: Operation not permitted
NiFi running with PID 28.
The specified run.as user nifi
 does not exist. Exiting.
Received trapped signal, beginning shutdown...
```

Below is my nifi.yml file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nifi-core
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nifi-core
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nifi-core
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nifi-core
          image: my-azurecr.io/nifi-core-prod:1.9.2
          env:
            - name: NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT
              value: "8080"
            - name: NIFI_VARIABLE_REGISTRY_PROPERTIES
              value: "./conf/custom.properties"
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: "6"
              memory: 12Gi
            limits:
              cpu: "6"
              memory: 12Gi
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          volumeMounts:
            - name: my-nifi-core-conf
              mountPath: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf
      volumes:
        - name: my-nifi-core-conf
          azureFile:
            shareName: my-file-nifi-core/nifi/conf
            secretName: my-nifi-secret
            readOnly: false
```

I have some customization in nifi `Dockerfile`, which copies some config files related to my configuration. When I ran `my-azurecr.io/nifi-core-prod:1.9.2` docker image on my local it works as expected
But when I try to run it on AKS its giving above error. since its related to permissions I have tried with both user `nifi` and `root` in Dockerfile.

All the required configuration files are provided in volume `my-nifi-core-conf` running in same resourse group.
Since I am starting `nifi` with docker my exception is, it will behave same regardless of environment. Either on my local or in AKS.
**But error also say user nifi does not exist.** The official [nifi-image](https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/nifi/dockerfile) setup the user requirement.

Can anyone help, I cant event start container in interaction mode as pods in not in running mode. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mount the volume to the same path inside the container locally and it works well? Maybe you use a wrong path. I see the `conf` path is `/opt/nifi/conf`. See the image nifi [Dockfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/nifi/dockerfile). Do you use this image?

Comment: the conf path is `/opt/nifi/nifi-current` :: `ENV NIFI_BASE_DIR=/opt/nifi` and 
`ENV NIFI_HOME ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-current` and finally `mkdir -p ${NIFI_HOME}/conf \`

Comment: OK, I made the mistake. Do you mount the volumes successfully locally?

Comment: Yes... the issue is with permission to modify the file

Comment: The `/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf` is just a file that you want to modify? It is not a directory?

Comment: its `dir` contains `conf` and `props` files.... that has to be user and group `nifi:nifi`

Answer (score 1):

I think your missing the Security Context definition for your Kubernetes Pod. The user that Nifi runs under within a Docker has a specific UID and GID, and with the error message you getting, I would suspect that because that user is not defined in the Pod's security context it's not launching as expected.

Have a look at section on the Kubernetes documentation about security contexts, and that should be enough get you started.

I would also have a look at using something like Minikube when testing Kubernetes deployments as Kubernetes adds a large number of controls around a container engine like Docker.

Security Contexts Docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/
Minikube: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/learning-environment/minikube/

Comment: Yes... I have read `securityContext`, and suspect the same. Somehow I able to figure out the owner of files and its `root:nifi` and it supposed to be `nifi:nifi`. `securityContext` allows only integer values.

Answer (score 1):

If you never figured this out, I was able to do this by running an initContainer before the main container, and changing the directory perms there.

```
initContainers:
      - name: init1
        image: busybox:1.28
        volumeMounts:
        - name: nifi-pvc
          mountPath: "/opt/nifi/nifi-current"
        command: ["sh", "-c", "chown -R 1000:1000 /opt/nifi/nifi-current"] #or whatever you want to do as root
```

Answer (score 0):

update: does not work with nifi 1.14.0 - works with 1.13.2

Answer (score 0):

For those following [this compose configurations](https://github.com/robcowart/docker_compose_cookbook/blob/master/nifi/docker-compose.yml), if you define any mounted volumes, they are also owned by the user `root` and group `root`. The default user-group of NiFi is `nifi:nifi`, so the created container cannot access the mounted directories, then shut down with the `Received trapped signal, beginning shutdown...` message. I don't know much about Linux systems and Docker stuff but after I `sudo chmod +777 -R` (not recommended) these directories, the NiFi container starts normally. Hope it helps!